# How to set where condition on parent and child table

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

In query below I want to select person by its id and I only want to include active addresses.  How do I write that query? I'm not sure the one I wrote is correct

Note that `GetQuery()` returns `IQueryable`

```
var person = repositoryProvider.Repository.GetQuery<Person>()
    .Where(a => a.PersonID == 1234 && a.Addresses.Any(x=>x.IsActive))
    .Include(a => a.Addresses)
    .Include(a => a.Employer)                   
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Which part are you unsure about? And when you tested it did you get the result you wanted?

Comment: Below is non working query.Query returns all PackageDetails for that Package
   var package = repositoryProvider.Repository.GetQuery<Package>()
                   .Where(a => a.PackageID == 1234 &&    a.PackageDetails.Any(x => x.IsExcludedFlag == false))
                   .Include(a => a.PackageBatch)                   
                   .Include(a => a.PackageDetails.Select(b => b.Document))
                   .Include(a => a.PackageSendHistories)
                   .Include(a => a.PackageSendHistories.Select(b => b.CompanyUser))
                   .SingleOrDefault();

Comment: im sorry but i dont know the trick to properly format this code

Answer (score 0):

From my reading, your query gets only person 1234 only if it has at least one active address. However, it will include all addresses related to Person 1234. For example, if person 1234 has one active and five inactive addresses, you will get Person 1234's details, together with its six total addresses, not just the active one.

For your purposes, I'm thinking a subquery would do.

```
var person = repositoryProvider.Repository.GetQuery<Person>()
             .Where (a => a.PersonID ==1234)
             .Include(a => a.Address)
             .Include(a => a.Employer)
             .Select (p => new Person { Id = p.Id,  // <-- set the person's properties that you need using the person details that you have extracted.
                      FirstName = p.FirstName,
                      Employer = p.Employer.ToList()
                      Addresses = p.Addresses.Where(a => a.IsActive == true) // <-- transform the resulting entity such that it will only return active addresses
                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

An alternative and probably easier to read method is to break it down into two parts. The first part will extract the person details:

```
var person = repositoryProvider.Repository.GetQuery<Person>()
             .Where (a => a.PersonID ==1234)
             .Include(a => a.Addresses)
             .Include(a => a.Employer)
             .Select (p => p);
```

and then the second part is limiting the addresses of the person to only the active addresses:

```
person.Addresses = person.Addresses.Where (a => a.IsActive == true).ToList();
```